# Battery shorting out in ESD mat?

Tags: batteries

So we are having a discussion on if an Anti-Static ESD mat would conduct current across the leads of a battery leading to a short.

The overall consensus is that the battery would short out.

Answer (score 3):

No, the resistance of a typical anti-static mat is far to high to cause significant current to flow from a typical battery. Did you try measuring the resistance?

Comment: Typically ESD mats are between 1 MOhm and 1 GOhm

Answer (score 3):

Indeed a current would flow but it will be a very small current, you would be nowhere near the current that would flow if the battery was shorted with a copper wire.

An ESD mat is conductive but not that much. For ESD a 1 Mega ohm resistance path is already enough for the charge to flow away in a safe and controlled way.

The not-that-low resistance of an ESD mat is high on purpose. Suppose you're working on some mains live equipment. If you touch a live connection you will suffer a much more severe shock if part of your body is touching a low-resistance grounded plate (like a grounded metal plate) than if you would be touching a high-resistance ESD mat. That's also why an (already high-resistance) ESD mat should be connected to ground via a 1 Mohm resistor. That's for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, yes, the battery would conduct across the mat, in essence a short. But in practice, it's not a dead short, where high current draws and high heat can occur, which is what most people would consider a "short". The short on a ESD mat is on the same level as leakage current or self discharge rates for a low voltage battery.

Comment: We are roughly at 2500 mAh in capacity say 3.6 V

Comment: 3.6V across 1 megaohm is 3.6 microamps. It would take decades to run it dry. The battery would self discharge faster than the ESD mat would.